# only show toolbar when enterAlways in CollapsingToolbarLayout with other view

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

**Layout** structure.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout .... >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout .... >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:background="@color/appbar"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imv_back"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_icon_padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/icons8_back" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:id="@+id/imv_tour_cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_height"
                    fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txv_tour_area"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_height"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Test string."
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txv_tour_title"
                style="@style/row_marginHorizontal_12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-34dp"
                android:text="Test string."
                android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_6" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tbl_tour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tablayout_height"
        android:background="@color/tab">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tbi_tour_stroke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text string." />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView .... />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView .... />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

First look like this.

[image: First look like this.]

When scroll down...**TabLayout** will set on top.

[image: When scroll down...]

Then scroll up a little, will expand part of **CollapsingToolbarLayout** (should be the toolbar's height).

[image: Then scroll up a little, will expand part of **CollapsingToolbarLayout**.]

Continue scrolling to the top, finally just like the first image.

My purpose is to show **only** **Toolbar** but not whole **CollapsingToolbarLayout** when *enterAlways*, the **LinearLayout**'s content is still hide until top when scroll, is it possible?